# Am I writing this exception handling cleanly?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I realize there are a few questions on best practices for exception handling, but I had to make a few tweaks on the examples I found. My goal was to get rid of basic exceptions like "ArgumentException", "FileNotFoundException", "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", etc.

If you can picture the following code in a hierarchy. So Process() calls ValidateData() which calls CSVData(). I am doing basically this same type of thing, **wrapping all of the known functions including my custom ones, then putting that in an exception for the method and passing it up as an inner exception. Is this a decent way to do this task?** It works for me, but I want to get in the habit of handling exceptions in a very clean way since some past projects of mine have been covered with "catch(Exception e)....and parse e.Message..."

Here's my example code:

```
public class CSVData
{
    DataTable data;
    public CSVData(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            this.data = CSVReader.ToDataTable(file); //throws a few basic exceptions
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file);
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException e)
        {
            throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file);
        }
    }

    class FailedLoadingCSVException : Exception
    {
        public int failedAtLine;

        public FailedLoadingCSVException(Exception e, int failedLine, string file)
            :base ("The system failed at loading "+file+" at line "+failedLine, e)
        {
            this.failedAtLine = failedLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really related to the question, but don't try to wrap `OutOfMemoryException`; if that exception happens, your whole application may be in an unstable state, so it's actually better to let it bubble up and crash your app than to risk some data loss.

Comment: it's not exception handling since you're throwing a new exception is just exception remapping. Which very often is with very little value

Comment: why so many exceptions ..? why not do a basic Try Catch and on the exception use (Exception e) write or log e.message or you can get a e.InnerException or even e.TargetSite.ToString() looks a bit like overkill

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, the exact opposite of my intentions here ;) That would make my code a pain to use and debug. I've learned to handle every exception that I can and only log unknowns

Comment: Most of the time, if you're not acting on an exception, you shouldn't catch it. If all you're doing is rethrowing, then it's better to not catch it because it leaves your code cleaner and doesn't mess with the stack information in the original exception.

Comment: @ChuckBlumreich, my problem is, I end up with 20 different things that could have called a "ArgumentNullException". My approach may be wrong, but this way I know what called the ArgumentNullException in the handler at the top of the hierarchy and I don't have to close the program and log an error, I just tell the user why they or their data is stupid.

Comment: @Brandon I agree with your statement but I believe that he may want to analyze the code he has and from there determine exactly what are the possible errors that may happen.. I personally like using e.TargetSite becasue it returns a lot as well as the Method and stacktrace / line it failed on and even better approach so he could make a custom method or class that he could call that handles all the possible exceptions that he's looking for and run a Case or enum case off of them. just an Idea..

Comment: @ChuckBlumreich that makes sense to me, so how should I do it, I need to know where in the code it occurred from the top level and easily translate that into instructions to the user of what to fix. Thoughts?

Comment: @Brandon I see your dilemma, turning stack information into a useful message for a user may be difficult. I imagine the object that contains this try/catch is not available to the location which is generating the user message. Assuming it isn't, right now I'd go with Wiktor's approach. That leaves it easy to hold the exception types you're handling specially in a collection, and you have 1 place to update the custom exception creation if that changes.

Comment: @Chuck Blumreich: If the caller of the `CVSData` constructor might want to recover from recoverable errors, without risking muddling on after unrecoverable ones, it must be able to distinguish between failures in which the only things that might have been corrupted were newly-created objects which have been jettisoned, and those in which other aspects of the system state were corrupted.  Your class might not be certain what an `ArgumentException` from `CvReader.ToDataTable()` means, but if you let it leak your caller will have no idea what an `ArgumentException` from you means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try
{
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
   if ( e is FileNotFoundException ||
        e is IOException ||
        // enumerate few 
       )
       throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file);
   else
       throw; // rethrow all other exceptions without touching them         
}
```

Comment: if that's the case he could do a Switch Case on the Exception as well but a simple Exception should work even if he did a stacktrace to.. his original code did not look like clean code.

Comment: This is definitely much cleaner, but it's the same in concept. I just wanted to know if it makes sense to send the exact exception and where it happened. Some of the other suggestions is to catch it at the top, but I seem to lose where the exception occurred and would have to go digging for it in the stack trace, which isn't fun to automate. I like this answer the best so far though.

Answer (score 0):

The body of each catch block is the same.  There's no need to catch the specific exception types in this case, because you are taking no type-specific action.  This is better:

```
   try 
    { 
        this.data = CSVReader.ToDataTable(file); //throws a few basic exceptions 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        throw new FailedLoadingCSVException(e, currentLine, file); 
    }
```

Comment: mapping exceptions is not the way to go. if you want the true exception why not just capture it at the e.message level.. many ways to skin the same cat..

Comment: Doing this would lose where it occurred. Most importantly to me, logically where it occurred. I need to translate this into instructions to the user. So if I said "An argument cannot be null" they would have no idea if I mean that for the file name, maybe a field was missing in the csv etc. I could find it in stack trace, but the mapping I'm doing seems to help me catch it logically in the right spot. I don't know though, I'm just trying to figure it out.

Comment: @brandon: How would this lose where it occurred?  It's the same logic that you have!  Your logic is rather like saying `if (x is int) return x.ToString(); if (x is short) return x.ToString(); if (x is double) return x.ToString();`  Or does it have something to do with `currentLine` (which is neither declared nor assigned anywhere in your example)?

Comment: @phoog, sorry forgot to tag DJ KRAZE in that message. The only issue I had with your answer was that it catches exceptions that I am unaware of. I try to put one general "Exception" per thread. Everything at this level would be catch specific exceptions and just bubble up any other exception since it's either out of context or I don't know what to do with it. If I ever catch a general exception at the root of the thread I log it and cry in a corner.

Answer (score -2):

```
try
{
    this.data = CSVReader.ToDataTable(file); //throws a few basic exceptions
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);        
}
//unless you know what the exact Exception of the CSVReader is you can always just use Base Exception Class..
```